# A better way to handle template creation?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++11

Trying to figure out a better design for this!

Consider that we have a template Image class that inherits from a template matrix library (in this case Eigen but it could be anything)

```
template <typename T>
class Image : public Eigen::Matrix <T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>
```

Now think of the case that we want to write a function to handle reading images from a file.
Of course images can be of different types, i.e. unisnged char, uint16_t, float and even have different channels as in grayscale, RGB or even RGBA.

So we could have of course template classes to easily handle this.As in

```
Image<RGB<unisgned char>> or Image<RGBA<float>>
```

Its simple when one knows the type of the image, say monochrome 8bit

```
Image<unisgned char> image = ReadImage(const char* const filename);
```

or it could even be

```
Image<unisgned char> image;
bool b = ReadImage(const char* const filename, Image<unisgned char>& image)
```

However when reading an image file we never know the type prior to reading the image.For example Tiff and png both support 8bit and 16 bit with tiff even supporting float.
In such cases its impossible to use any of the functions mentioned above. However, we can have a temmplate Factory class to sort that out.

For that we first need to introduce a BaseImage class

```
class BaseImage
{
public:
    inline BaseImage() {};
    virtual inline ~BaseImage() {};

    virtual inline int Width() const = 0;
    virtual inline int Height() const = 0;
    virtual inline int Depth() const = 0;
    etc...
};

template <typename T>
class Image : public BaseImage, public Eigen::Matrix <T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>
```

Then we can have our factory class where we pass our unsigned char*, float*, etc.. and let it handle the creation

```
class ImageFactory
{
  typename <T>
  static BaseImage* createImage(const T* const src, const int& width, const int& height, const int& depth)
  {
    if (depth == 1)
    {
      return new Image<T>();
    }
    else if (depth == 3)
    {
      return new Image<RGB<T>>();
    }
    etc...
  }
}
```

Of course this forces me to use dynamic allocation and inheritance.

I guess I can get around the dynamic allocation by hiding it inside a class that takes care of it.
In the constructor the factory clas will be called

```
class Image2
{
public:
    Image2(const char* const path)
    {
        // where ReadImage and external function that will call ImageFactory
        pBaseImage = ReadImage(path);
    }
    ~Image2();

private:
    BaseImage* pBaseImage;
};
```

In either case my BaseImage class will have to expose all the functionality that I need to use from my matrix library which kinda defies the purpose of inheriting.

The question is then if there is a better design than could be used here cause its becoming quite cumbersome

Comment: Why would you use templates here ? I would rather use a simple union (or [variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/variant.html)) inside a single class `Image`. Also, can you show an exemple of an image "of type `float`" ? Do you mean that points would be represented by a color of floating-point values ?

Comment: @Nelxiost That would be slow as hell. `float` is for the monochrome images.

Comment: To have access to those fields only from your matrix library, you could either define as much as you can inside that `BaseImage` class or use `friend`s to expose fields to the places you need them only.

Comment: Why would you use a matrix for an image?  While both are 2 dimensionally organized data, one of them is basically a linear transformation, and the other ... really isn't.

Comment: @Nexiost Indeed union is something that I considered but apart from slow it will also require more memory for the case that I am just using unsigned char*

Comment: @Yakk the memory layout of Eigen is actually exactly the same as using just a raw buffer. As I said I could easily just map the raw buffer to eigen. Using Eigen and templates I can facilitate transformations and various other operations, e.g easily convert to grayscale or any other type, bilinear bicubic transformations, concatenate images easily and so on...

Comment: An alternative is indeed to just have a raw buffer (whose type I wont know until I read the image header). The raw buffer can be wrapped nicely around a class to hide the ugliness of void* (or unisnged char*) and I will have to have a type of some sort to distinguish it. Then I guess I could use type_traits and create my Image<T> template at a later stage if needed. That was another thought that I had but I was not fond of the two-stage construction.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Yeah defining what I need is indeed is a solution but duplication. Friend was something that I did not really think. Friend to a template class ! Will have to look on that but it seems to me that I am over complicating the design... 

Hiding everything in Image2 class as mentioned in my first post and then using type traits to get an Image<T> is probably my best option I think.

Comment: @xerion The approach of having a raw buffer and creating an Image<T> out of it on demand is actually the best possible design if you want to be type safe. It also has the advantage of allowing you to use the same data in different ways for different purposes. For instance you can have a RGBA image of type int32 and width equal to the number of pixels but for other purposes treat the same image as uint8 with width equal to the stride of the image. You just create a ImageBuffer class to load the image and encapsulate the memory and add a templated function to return Image<T> from the data

Comment: `BaseImage` in fact cannot sensibly expose almost any functionality that manipulates individual pixels. It can expose high-level functions like "scale" or "posterize" or whatever, that manipulate the entire image. It is not clear to me why this organization defies anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'd post this as a comment if I could show code in a comment ... to me, this seems obvious enough, and you probably thought of it.  Why isn't it what you're looking for?

```
class Image
{
public:
  Image (int bytesPerPixelIn = 1) { data_ = NULL; bytesPerPixel=bytesPerPixelIn;};

  void readImage (int width, int height);
private:
  int       bytesPerPixel_;
  void*     data_;
};

void Image::read (int width, int height, ...)
{
   data_ = new unsigned char [width*height*pixelSize(imageType_)];
   //...
}

//And you can inherit from this if need be to add special functions 
//like interleaving in BMP files
```

Edit:  OK, I see.  Would this serve better?

```
template <typename PixelType>
class Image
{
public:
  Image () { data_ = NULL; };

  virtual void allocateImage (int width, int height)
  {
    data_ = new PixelType [width*height]; 
  }
  virtual void readImage (int width, int height) = 0;
private:
  PixelType*     data_;
};

template <typename PixelType>
class ImageTIFF: public Image <PixelType> ...
```

or this:

```
template <typename PixelType, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT>
class Image
{
public:
  Image () { }

  virtual void readImage () = 0;
private:
  PixelType*     data_ [WIDTH][HEIGHT];
};

template <typename PixelType, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT>
class ImageTIFF: public Image <PixelType, WIDTH, HEIGHT> ...
```

The latter eliminates dynamic memory... but without dynamic memory, you can't have a resize function.  I'd use dynamic memory.

You'll need inheritance for different file formats, surely, as they don't read images the same way.

--

OK.  How about this?  BaseImage here is like a Java "interface," and will ensure that the derived classes have the functions they'll need.

```
class BaseImage 
{
public:
  virtual void allocateImage (int width, int height) = 0;
  virtual void readImage     (int width, int height) = 0;
};

template <typename PixelType>
class Image: public BaseImage ... /* and so on */

BaseImage* myTIFFImage = readTIFFImage (/* whatever goes here */);
```

Comment: Not really generic nor type safe. You would have to write code for each type that an image can hold.
Also it wont help the compiler do optimizations such as vectorization (could be wrong on this one).

Comment: Certainly the dynamic memory option is better, but I guess the main problem is what do you return from your readTiffImage(const char*) function ? Tiff can hold various types and the only solution is then to have a base class that you can return which is what I am also thinking. The only difference is how we structure the base class with me relying to Eigen for their optimisations.

Comment: Since you need readTIFFImage to return a class that doesn't specify anything, including pixel type, well, that sounds like a base class that specifies some needed functions, especially readImage, but nothing else.  I put code above for what looks like a solution; see what you think.